# how can i apply convolution to a stereo audio signal?

Tags: python, numpy

> here's my code, but i don't know how to apply convolution to a stereo audio signal, i could only apply it to one channel instead of both, so i want to know if is possible to apply convolution between an array 1d to an aray 2d (stereo audio signal)

```
import  numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
import  sounddevice as sd

delay=22050

x, FS = sf.read('acdc-stereo.wav', dtype='float')
print(x)
zeros = np.zeros(delay-1,dtype='float')
h = np.concatenate(([1],zeros,[0.3]))

print('Processing..')
y = np.convolve(x[:,0],h, mode="full")
newaudio=(y,FS)
print(y)
print('Playing original signal')
sd.play(x,FS)
sd.wait()
print("playing output signal")
sd.play(newaudio)
sd.wait()
```

Comment: It looks like there might be some help here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/18341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numpy array is a frames x channel array. And in this line:

```
y = np.convolve(x[:,0],h, mode="full")
```

You did convolution only to channel 0. You should apply it to other channels as well if you mean to. I think for most realistic cases, convolution should be applied separately to different channels:

```
y = np.array([np.convolve(x[:,0], h, mode="full"),
              np.convolve(x[:,1], h, mode="full")]).T
```

Comment: I tried but I don't know how to join the results again to play the modified signal

Comment: i just tried it but that gives me this error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1371423) into shape (1349373), and i dont know why cause if i only put this y = np.convolve(x[:,0],h, mode="full") it doesnt give that error but the thing is that is only one channel

Comment: overlooked your convolution. That's because your convolution result is shorter than the input size, so you can't directly assign. Updated code to create it instead.

Comment: thank you so much thas what i needed, one tip to save that modfied signal into a .wav file?

Comment: `sf.write('new_file.wav', data, samplerate)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more elegant:

```py
stereoOutput = np.array(
    [ np.convolve(monoFoo, ch) for ch in stereoBar ]
)
```

Only works if you're using 2 cols for your stereo signal (instead of 2 rows).